# There is any WCF binding that accepts the data in a HTTP query string?

Tags: wcf, http, binding, query-string, wcf-binding

There is any WCF binding that accepts the data in a HTTP query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webHttpBinding` might be what you want...  [Clicky](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wcf+webHttpBinding)

Comment: The first result was just what I wanted
http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/archive/2008/10/08/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well, WCF also supports REST, which sort of allows you to specify the parameters for your call in the URL.

- [MSDN WCF REST Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx) - tons of goodies, including screen casts
- [An Introduction To RESTful Services With WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx)
- [The new WCF Web Programming Model supports REST Design](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/05/wcf-web-programming-model)

Is that what you're looking for? I don't think there's any standard way to package up a SOAP envelope on the query string.....